# Is there a C function to get the size of a file's data segment?

Tags: c, linux, data-segment

I'm wondering if there's a C function that can be used to get another executable file's data segment size? For example, something that works like the `size` utility in Linux? The output of `size` includes the information I'm after, the data segment size; for example, it might look like:

```
text    data    bss     dec     hex     filename
294880  81920   11592   388392  5ed28   ranlib
```

Comment: Start with `man elf` - that will lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Check Binutils' [BFD library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_File_Descriptor_library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `elf.h` you have all the data structures you need. Follow the main ELF header to the program headers, then iterate through them. The `PT_LOAD` header(s) with write permission is/are the data segment(s).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there's single function to get it, but the size source code is pretty small (~500 lines). Is what you're looking for in here?
https://github.com/pathscale/binutils/blob/master/binutils/size.c